# accessing response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value globally

Tags: javascript, maps, distance

This is the code I have and I want `calcRoute()` to be executed first and to return the `strDistance` variable value and after that I want the next function call `newPassenger()`  to be executed.. But its not working that way. It executes the `newPassenger()`; first and then `calcRoute()` .. Please help!

```
function calcRoute() {
    var calcRoute = function (origin, destination, cb) {
        var dist;
        //var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        //directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var request = {
            origin: strorig, // a city, full address, landmark etc
            destination: strdest,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                //directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                cb(null, response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000);
            }
            else {
                cb('pass error information');
            }
        });
    };
    calcRoute(strorig, strdest, function (err, dist) {
        if (!err) {
            alert("distance" + dist);
            strDistance = dist;
        }
    });
    newPassenger();
}
```

Comment: I believe you would just need to move calling `newPassenger();` to within your `calcRoute` callback function.

Comment: Ha...Thanks a million @snapjs .This is a big help!